# Removing lookup widget from QGIS statusBar

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'd like to programmatically (using PyQGIS) remove the lookup widget ('Type to locate') appearing at the left of the QGIS statusBar.

I was thinking that maybe something like `iface.mainWindow().statusBar().removeWidget(???)` could work. However, I don't know which would be the widget name or even if there might be an alternative approach to the `removeWidget` method.

I'm using QGIS 3.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so pretty, but it works. Just hide, not remove.

```
for w in iface.statusBarIface().children():
    if w.__class__.__name__ == 'QWidget':
        for c in w.children():
            if c.__class__.__name__ == 'QgsFilterLineEdit':
                print('Thank you RainForest )))')
                w.hide()
                break
```

Comment: To make it a little more succinct, you can use `if isinstance(w, QWidget):` and `if isinstance(c, QgsFilterLineEdit):`.

Comment: It seems like the question was closed but I still was able to accept the answer. Thanks!